# Django - Creating a row in onther table before creating user

Tags: django

I have user, userprofile and company tables.

I want to create a record in company table and then assign the id of the newly created company in the userprofile foreign key before creating the user. I think it can be done using pre_save signal but I am unable to figure how. Please help.

Here's some details as AMG asked:

I have django's builtin user model

a userprofile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpeg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Biography')
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

a company model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Company Name")
    nof = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="No. of Employees")
```

All three are related user and userprofile has one to one relationship, and userprofile and company has many to one relationship.

I want Company record to be created first and than that new record's reference needs to be put into userprofile.

I think I have made it clear now.

Comment: Hi Majid. If you provide some more detail (like your models) it would be easier to assist. If you provide the minimum amount of code to make it easier to have specifics, you'll get a more specific response for your situation.

Comment: I added some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you can use pre_save for this. You can just put this in `models.py` below your defined models.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)                    # register your model to the signal pre_save
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs): 
    if not instance.company_name:                      # check if instance has a value for company_name
        company = Company.objects.create(              
            name='Test',
            nof=1
        )
        instance.company_name = company
```

**OR**

Create a default value through a function.

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Company Name") # set blank=true and null=true so you can save an empty instance
    nof = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="No. of Employees")

def profile_company_default():
    return Company.objects.create()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpeg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Biography')
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=profile_company_default) # add function as default value
```

**EDIT**

To edit company after save.

```
profile = Profile.objects.create(key="value")
profile.company.name = "Company Name"
profile.company.nof = 5
profile.save()
```

Comment: This is perfect although I would like to ask another thing, if I want to pass value into pre_save signal from POST how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can, but I added an edit at the end on how you can change the company instance, i guess that's your goal.